# Twitter Bootstrap: gutters

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

From my understanding, gutters are the white space between columns. Questions:

1. In Bootstrap, I assume gutters are the spaces between `.container` and `.container-fluid`. Is this correct?
2. Gutter width seems to be between 20px - 30px based on display size. What to do if the design doesn't require spacing between containers?

Answer (score 9):

#### 1. Gutters

Gutters are the space between `.span`, whether it's in a `.row` or a `.row-fluid`. But the gutter width is defined by a different setting for the normal grid and the fluid one (one is fixed in `px`, the other is relative in `%`).

Additional values are set depending on the screen width, if you use the responsive layout.

[Check this doc](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) ([same with v3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options))

**Important :** the gutter width is used in several others rules, for example the `margin-left` of the `.row`, or the `width` of the `.container`.

#### 2. No gutters

Gutter widths are defined as LESS variables. If you want to use a grid that doesn't have gutters, you should download a [customized version of bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables) - see **Grid System** ([same with v3](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics)).

I myself prefer to download the LESS files, import an override file after `variables.less`, set my own variables and compile it myself, so that I can upgrade Bootstrap without worrying about my previous modifications.

Comment: Both these links are broken

Comment: @portforwardpodcast links fixed to both latest v2 and v3 docs